# How to save frames in another matlab file without making them visible

Tags: matlab, video

I have a video and I am doing some processing on the frames of video in matlab(mfile). After that the frames are compiled and a video is made by using those processed frames. There are about 300 frames in the video. As processing is quite heavy so my computer freezes. I just don't want to show those processed frames rather I want that those frames should be stored in another mfile. I know the commands like `saveas` or `set(gcf,'visible','off')` but they don't work in my case. 
 What I have so far:

```
aviobj =avifile('trail.avi','Compression','None','fps',1); %video to be made from frames
obj = aviread('highwayvideo.avi');
for 1:300
    .......... % processing
imi = getframe(gcf);
aviobj = addframe(aviobj,imi);
end
aviobj = close(aviobj);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using current figure for - it is not clear from the code posted... Is it possible to process obj without displaying anything on the figure at all?

Comment: My"processing" involves drawing things on the frame. So it is necessary to show them.

Comment: Are you creating a new image for each frame, or using same image for all frames? By that I mean - using imshow(...); for each frame, it will create 300 images in one figure at the end and will be very slow. Another option would be to do h=imshow(...);  once and then do set(h,'CData',NewFrame);. Alternatively, you can just delete and recreate figure each time (slower since creating figure takes time, but still more efficient then putting all images within one figure). You can check number of objects contained in the figure by doing h=get(gcf,'Children'); and checking number of elements in h.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear but sounds like you are suffering from a RAM limitation of some kind. MATLAB's video conversion routines are unnecessarily expensive, there are better ways to do that stuff. I'd recommend processing the input video and saving the 300 frames as image files, then using ffmpeg to compile them into a video. You may even want to use ffmpeg to convert the input video to input stills and just load the stills into matlab one at a time.

Comment: If I will save the frame as an image the problem still remains the same as in that case I have to show every frame. Actually  "processing" involves drawing things on the frame. The real reason why it gets slower and slower as it goes on is that I am displaying it in the same container (an axes control).so all 300 frames are trying to get stuffed into it. Any other suggestion.